# Serialize single dimensional array to 3d RGB array for jpeg compression

Tags: arrays, compression, jpeg, rgb

I'm trying to serialize a 1d array to a 3d RGB array and then use jpeg lossy compression to compress that RGB array, finally the RGB array must be de-serialized back to a 1d array. What's important is, jpeg compresses according to colors, meaning similar colors must have similar values.

Each value in the original 1d data must also be able to be stored in the RGB array/image across all 3 color channels. I.e each value should be able to be serialized to 256^3 possible values assuming an 8bit image.

With this in mind, I'd like to know any ideas you all might have in order to accomplish this. The difficulty is storing the data in such a way, that similar values always have similar colors, so that the data can survive jpeg compression.

In case it wasn't clear, the goal of this project is data compression.

Answer (score 0):

To say you a step, while not specified in the JPEG standard, JPEG compression is normally done on YCbCr data.

You could take an existing encoder and see what format it wants the data after the RGB to YCbCr conversion, then do that conversion yourself from your input format to whatever the encoders expects at that stage.